# Progress on rounded progress bar is not showing in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, progress-bar

So i want to create a progress bar that is rounded but for some reason the inner progress layer is not showing.

Here is what i tried:
the code for progressbarbg.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadius="64dp"
            android:thickness="8dp"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:innerRadius="64dp"
                android:thickness="8dp"
                android:useLevel="true">

                <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and here is the code for progressBar itself:

```
<ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbarbg"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:max="500"
                        />
```

[image: here is how its appearing:]